# start software as different user in autostart on windows 10

Tags: windows, startup, autostart

I've a monitoring software which should be started on a production system where the logged in user can do nearly nothing, not even access most of the directories on the windows system although on startup we have a control panel software which should be able to access everthing on the system - so my question:
Is it possible to start a piece of software on startup automatically of windows 10 without any restrictions and log in to the system as different user? The Software does not run as a service so thats no option. 
i have already found out the way of bringing back the context menu entry "start as different user" which is also no option in this case.

Answer (score 3):

I searched around an found the following solution:

- First download the PSTools for Windows 
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pstools
- Then create a batch file e.g. sample.bat
- Insert this Line c:/tools/pstools/psexec -u xxx -p xxx "C:\startprogramm.exe" were -u > username -p > password and the program to start
- Place the sample.bat into the Autostart of Windows c:/user/AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

This should start the program under a different username - try it with a adminuser and a standarduser - at least it worked out for me!